# Sync while-loops on differents tasks with OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to use openMP on C, but I don't know how to sync two whiles on differents tasks.

Each step in the while-loops depends on all previous steps. It is an implementation for simulating hardware, if anyone was wondering.

I need that both loops start each iteration at the same time and the loop which ends his iteration first, wait the other loop. I don't know if OMP has something to do this or how I should do manually

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp master
{
#pragma omp task
while(...) // will be run some hundreds of millions of times
{
    ...
}

#pragma omp task
while(...) // will be run some hundreds of millions of times
{
    ...
}

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I think this would need some locking mechanism. However, this kind of problem seems more suited for a simple parallel work construct where you split the work inside the while loop between two threads, then put a barrier inside.